# How do I handle user response (facebook) chat bot?

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, bots, facebook-chatbot

Trying to create a facebook chatbot with NodeJS.

The problem is that I can easily handle user response to "button" messages with few choices to pick but can't handle input from simple text messages ("what is your favourite color?").

The conversation should be as follows :

**Bot** : Welcome, I have some questions for you. 
What is your phone number?

**User** :

**Bot** : How old are you?

**User** : 
etc.

So what would be the way out to make this flow of question->answer possible?

My code so far:

```
let messaging_events = req.body.entry[0].messaging;
for (let i = 0; i < messaging_events.length; i++) {
    let event = messaging_events[i];
      if (event.message && event.message.text) {
         let text = event.message.text;
         let textid = event.message.mid;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this module [facebook-chat-api](https://github.com/Schmavery/facebook-chat-api).
Or read it to learn how to create it.
And are you using facebook-graph-api or login with NodeJs ?

Comment: I'm using facebook-graph-api.

Thanks for your answer @HồngTừAnh, I'll try this. 
Still wondering if there is any solution for this case using official api.
Appreciate your help though